# Sort by number of apearances

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

for example, I am given a word and I have to sort its letters by the number of occurrences in that word, if 2 letters appear the same number of times it will be sorted by the lexicographic minimum.
For now, I have started to see how many times a letter appears in a word but from here I do not know exactly how to do it.
The problem requires me to use BufferedReader and BufferedWriter.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Map<Character, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (m.containsKey(c))
            m.put(c, m.get(c) + 1);
        else
            m.put(c, 1);
    }
    for (char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; ++letter)
        if (m.containsKey(letter))
            System.out.println(letter + ": " + m.get(letter));
}
```

For the moment I am posting what letters appear most often in the word, but I do not know how to sort them by the number of occurrences and in case there are two letters that appear at the same number of times with the minimum lexicographic.

Comment: is there any real reason to use buffered writer?

Comment: Add some examples to the question, i.e. input -> output. This way you can clarify stuff much better.

Comment: related/same course/problem: [Sort the letters of a word](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60302758/85421) (same person: [STRKLok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12926383/strklok)? same code???)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you want

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Character, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
    String testString = "Instructions";
    Map<Character, List<Character>> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < testString.length(); i++) {
        char someChar = testString.charAt(i);
        if (someChar == ' ') {
            continue;
        }
        char ch = testString.charAt(i);
        List<Character> characters = map.getOrDefault(Character.toLowerCase(ch), new ArrayList<>());
        characters.add(ch);
        map.put(Character.toLowerCase(ch), characters);
    }
    List<Map.Entry<Character, List<Character>>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());

    list.sort((o1, o2) -> {
        if (o1.getValue().size() == o2.getValue().size()) {
            return o1.getKey() - o2.getKey();/// your lexicographic comparing
        }
        return o2.getValue().size() - o1.getValue().size();
    });

    list.forEach(entry -> entry.getValue().forEach(System.out::print));
}
```

Comment: It's ok but a question that helps me at the end of the problem.
For example I have as input:
  Instructions;
As output it must show me:
iinnttcuoss.
That is, the letters sorted by the number of frequencies and alphabetically in case two letters appear the same number of times.

Comment: modified for you)

Comment: "prog.java:23: error: ')' expected
        list.sort((o1, o2) -> {", Ok, when I want to test the problem I get this error, possibly from Java version or idea?

Comment: use sdk 8 or substitute lambda to anonym class

Answer (score 0):

To count letters in word, you can use much simpler method:

define array with 26 zeros, scan input line and increase appropriate index in this array, so if you meet 'a' (or 'A' - which is the same letter, but different symbol) - you will increase value at index 0, b - index 1, etc

during this scan you can also compute most occurred symbol, like this:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    char maxSymbol = 0;
    int maxCount = 0;

    final int[] counts = new int[26]; // number of times each letter (a-z) appears in string
    try (final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
        final String s = br.readLine().toLowerCase(); // calculate case-insensitive counts
        for (final char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            final int idx = c - 'a'; // convert form ASCII code to 0-based index
            counts[idx]++;

            if (counts[idx] > maxCount) {
                maxSymbol = c; // we found most occurred symbol for the current moment
                maxCount = counts[idx];
            } else if (counts[idx] == maxCount) { // we found 2nd most occurred symbol for the current moment, need to check which one is minimal in lexicographical order
                if (c < maxSymbol) {
                    maxSymbol = c;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (maxSymbol > 0) {
        System.out.println("Most frequent symbol " + maxSymbol + " occurred " + maxCount);
    }
}
```

I've used buffered reader to get data from stdin, but I have no idea where to put buffered writer here, maybe to print result?